# Rails 3 best_in_place_if how to show confirm alert box before the action gets completed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I am using best_in_place_if for inline editing. Here a column value gets changed just by clicking on the value. Suppose column is status and values are 'yes' and 'no'. So its like a toggle effect. If user clicks on this column, then a call goes to server and it fires a query to toggle the value in database.

I want to show a alert box showing a confirmation message, like we do for delete. If user clicks on yes then fine otherwise do not complete the call.

```
best_in_place_if(current_user.admin,trip,:is_active, :type => :checkbox, :classes => 'trip_disable')
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it rails-esque I would try to leverage jquery-ujs and the data-confirm attribute we rails devs love so much.  Try wrapping the best_in_place call inside a span inside a link with the data-confirm option being called on it.  Such as:

```
   <%= link_to(trip) do %>
     <span><%= best_in_place trip, :is_active, type: :checkbox, classes: 'trip_disable', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %> </span> 
   <% end %>
```

You may have to shift the span around I did this from my phone so the format may be off a little.